# How to get rid of an additional duplicate record using rank() function in sql?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have the following 2 records:

| key | start_dt | end_dt | id | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 2020-8-12 | 2300-01-01 | 1 | active |
| 12 | 1998-9-23 | 2014-9-23 | 2 | active |

This is the `row_number()` function I currently have:

```
row_number() over (partition by id order by status, end_dt desc) rnk
```

I want to know what I need to add to the above `row_number()` function so that only the top record is showing:

| key | start_dt | end_dt | id | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 2020-8-12 | 2300-01-01 | 1 | active |

Comment: Why are you partitioning on `id` if you want `key` to be unique? PS - don't alias a row_number() derivation as rnk. Could be very confusing because a similar, but different, rank() function exists.

Comment: no need for rank or row_number, if you need the  lowest `id` for each key : `SELECT ... from tbl qualify id=min(id)  over (partition by key)`

Comment: So, for each key, you want only the row with the maximum end_dt?

Answer (score -1):

Here's how I would do it for SQL Server.  For BigQuery, your syntax will differ a little but I'm sure the structure will be the same.

```
create table #a (
    [key] int
  , start_dt date
  , end_dt date
  , id int
  , status varchar(20)
)
insert into a
values 
  (12, {d '2020-08-12'}, {d '2300-01-01'}, 1, 'active')
, (12, {d '1998-09-23'}, {d '2014-09-23'}, 2, 'active')
;
with
b as (
  select 
    [key]
  , start_dt
  , end_dt
  , id
  , status
  , max(end_dt) over (partition by [key]) as maxenddt
  from #a
)
select
  [key]
, start_dt
, end_dt
, id
, status
from b
where end_dt = maxenddt
```